# What is the name of this small component inside Shimano Tourney STI

Tags: parts

What is the name of the component outlined in red in the image, that seats the head of the brake cable?

[image]

Comment: Brake cable anchor?

Comment: Have you lost yours ?

Comment: Criggie - The one on the opposite STI to the one in the picture came without the white plastic ends. Cable can still be seated with just the middle part of the cable hook, but not as intended.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This part is officially called "cable hook" and "cable hook unit" in Shimano docs. See attached image (I won't link it because the PDF is not hosted by Shimano) and [this document](http://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-ST0001-05-ENG.pdf) (page 7).

[image: Tourney STI blow chart]

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed called a Cable Hook, and can be bought here: https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/gear-spares/shimano-str700-cable-hook-unit-6cu-9805/

Comment: Good finding.  Do you have any affiliation or association with that site?  If so, SE rules require you to say so clearly.

Comment: @Criggie No affiliation at all. I have shopped there a few times, they are my go-to shop for obscure bike parts.